# NFC/RFID module multiple cards

Tags: nfc, rfid, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I have [this NFC module](https://www.itead.cc/wiki/RDM8800). When i read ONE card at a moment everything works fine, but I need to read more that one card at a moment.

One card laying on a module - module reads it ok, when I move another card over the module, I get a mix of both card's numbers.

Is there any way to read both card at one moment correctly?

I read card like this. As a bord I use [NodeMCU ESP8266 ESP-12E](https://www.banggood.com/Geekcreit-Doit-NodeMcu-Lua-ESP8266-ESP-12E-WIFI-Development-Board-p-985891.html)

```
SoftwareSerial rfid(RFID_RX, RFID_TX);
..
void loop()
{
    rfid.listen();
    delay(500);

    while (rfid.available() > 0) {
        Serial.println("Closest card number: " + rfid.readString());
    }

}
```

Comment: IMHO, RFID isn't designed for MIMO. You'd better give it up.

Comment: What exactly do you get for `rfid.readString()` (with one card and two cards respectively)? Looking at the schematics of the reader module, it seems that the module uses a PN532. And the source code suggests that the module is used to poll for ISO/IEC 14443A cards with support anti-collision and enumeration of multiple tags. The module should enumerate only one card though.

Comment: @MichaelRoland, for one card the result of method is repeated card number with \n break. like 123\n123\n123\n. For more that one card the result is mix of both card's number. 1 - 123, 2 - 353, result - 2355234\n124131\n1241341 ..and so on

Comment: @OlehKurpiak Those were certainly not the values you received from the board (if the board uses the firmware from your link). That firmware would always output 10 decimal digits for a serial number...

Answer (score -2):

As the comments suggest this is quite hard.

If you want to read more cards you can maybe use the PN532, According to [this](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=35050) thread with the board developer it can read 2 cards simultaneously.

Comment: The module mentioned in the question *does* use a PN532 so your answer does not make any sense.